# Laplace transform of delays Sinc function

Tags: linear-algebra, laplace-transform

I am trying to compute the Laplace transform of the following Sinc function,

$$\operatorname{sinc}(a(t-t_0)) = \frac{\sin(a(t-t_0))}{a(t-t_0)} $$

Where, $t_0$ is the delay and $a$ is constant value.

I know the Laplace transform for $\frac{\sin(at)}{at}$ without delay is $\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{s}{a}\right)\right)$. I am concerned whether we can use the phase shift property (i.e. multiply by $\exp(-st_0)$) or not, as the function has non-zero values on the negative axis as well?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition):

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{sinc}\left(\alpha\left(x-x_0\right)\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\text{sinc}\left(\alpha\left(x-x_0\right)\right)\exp\left(-\text{s}x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

It is not hard to [show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Series_expansion) that (using [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition)) $\forall\text{n}$:

$$\text{sinc}\left(\text{n}\right)=\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\text{n}^{2\text{k}}}{\left(2\text{k}+1\right)!}\tag2$$

So, using that we can rewrite $(1)$ as follows:

$$\mathscr{L}_x\left[\text{sinc}\left(\alpha\left(x-x_0\right)\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\int_0^\infty\left\{\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\left(\alpha\left(x-x_0\right)\right)^{2\text{k}}}{\left(2\text{k}+1\right)!}\right\}\cdot\exp\left(-\text{s}x\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\alpha^{2\text{k}}}{\left(2\text{k}+1\right)!}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\infty\left(x-x_0\right)^{2\text{k}}\exp\left(-\text{s}x\right)\space\text{d}x\right\}\tag3$$

Now, let's take a look at a slightly different integral:

$$\mathcal{I}_\beta:=\int_0^\beta\left(x-x_0\right)^{2\text{k}}\exp\left(-\text{s}x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag4$$

First, let $\text{u}:=\left(x-x_0\right)^{2\text{k}+1}$, this leads to:

$$\mathcal{I}_\beta=\frac{\exp\left(-\text{s}x_0\right)}{2\text{k}+1}\int_{\left(-x_0\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}^{\left(\beta-x_0\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}\exp\left(-\text{s}\cdot\text{u}^\frac{1}{2\text{k}+1}\right)\space\text{du}\tag5$$

Now, let $\text{v}:=\text{us}^{2\text{k}+1}$, this leads to:

$$\mathcal{I}_\beta=\frac{\exp\left(-\text{s}x_0\right)}{\left(2\text{k}+1\right)\text{s}^{2\text{k}+1}}\int_{\left(-x_0\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}^{\left(\left(\beta-x_0\right)\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}\exp\left(-\text{v}^\frac{1}{2\text{k}+1}\right)\space\text{dv}\tag6$$

And this is a special function, called the [Incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition):

$$\mathcal{I}_\beta=\frac{\exp\left(-\text{s}x_0\right)}{\left(2\text{k}+1\right)\text{s}^{2\text{k}+1}}\cdot\left[-\left(2\text{k}+1\right)\Gamma\left(2\text{k}+1,\text{v}^\frac{1}{2\text{k}+1}\right)\right]_{\left(-x_0\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}^{\left(\left(\beta-x_0\right)\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}=$$
$$\frac{-\left(2\text{k}+1\right)\exp\left(-\text{s}x_0\right)}{\left(2\text{k}+1\right)\text{s}^{2\text{k}+1}}\cdot\left[\Gamma\left(2\text{k}+1,\text{v}^\frac{1}{2\text{k}+1}\right)\right]_{\left(-x_0\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}^{\left(\left(\beta-x_0\right)\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}=$$
$$\frac{\exp\left(-\text{s}x_0\right)}{\text{s}^{2\text{k}+1}}\cdot\left[\Gamma\left(2\text{k}+1,\text{v}^\frac{1}{2\text{k}+1}\right)\right]_{\left(\left(\beta-x_0\right)\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}^{\left(-x_0\text{s}\right)^{2\text{k}+1}}\tag7$$

Comment: Thanks, @Jan, for detailed explanation. My intent of using the Laplace transform of sinc is to numerically solve a PDE in Laplace domain (for some reason) with sinc as the source, and then recover the time domain solution using Numerical Laplace inversion. Could you maybe suggest another approach that avoids numerical calculation of Incomplete Gamma function (IGF)? Since, I am using MATLAB and the built-in function for IGF works only for real values.